# Unable to fetch date data in HTml <input type= 'date'> from database

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have a input box in HTML

```
<label>Holiday</label>
<input type="date"  class="form-control" asp-for="HolidayDate" >
```

In this field I want data from my Database in sqlserver. For this I used the code on button click

code for javascript

```
<script>`javascript`
  $(".btnGet").click(function () {
            var origin = window.location.origin;
            $.post(origin + "/HolidayMaster/Edit //my controller page
                { Id: $(this).attr("data-id") }, //id for fetching data
                function (response) {
                    $("#HolidayMasterId").val(response.holidayMasterId)`primary key`
                   $("#HolidayDate").val(response.holidayDate)
                  
                }
            );
        });

</script>
```

Here `HolidayMaster` is my controller

My question is I am unable to bring date in form control but Function(response) fetch data from Database.

Comment: Hi @Nidhi Aggarwal, how is your backend code like? Did you check `response` if it returns data? You can add `console.log(response)` to check in the Console panel(F12) in browser

Comment: Besides, if it contains value, try to change `type="date"` to `type="text"` or `type="type="datetime"`.

Comment: @Rena yes response returns data as well type="text" takes value but type="date" not able to get data I Want my data in type="date"

Comment: Hi @Nidhi Aggarwal, I've shared an answer below. Pls check. If any update, remember to follow up to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Datetime is different from JavaScript Date, be sure convert like below:

```
$(".btnGet").click(function () {
        var origin = window.location.origin;
        $.post(origin + "/HolidayMaster/Edit", 
            { Id: $(this).attr("data-id") }, //id for fetching data
            function (response) {                   
                $("#HolidayMasterId").val(response.holidayMasterId)
                $("#HolidayDate").val(new Date(Date.parse(response.holidayDate)).toDateInputValue())          
            }
        );
    });
Date.prototype.toDateInputValue = (function() {
    var local = new Date(this);
    local.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() - this.getTimezoneOffset());
    return local.toJSON().slice(0,10);
});
```